# Vim errorformat for phpunit

Tags: vim, phpunit

I'm working on a Vim compiler plugin for PHPUnit.

I've written the following `errorformat`. The error message is correctly extracted, but file and line numbers are not.

```
CompilerSet errorformat=%E%n)\ %.%#,
                       \%C%m,
                       \%+C%$,
                       \%C%f:%l,
                       \%Z%$
```

PHPUnit's output looks something like this:

```
PHPUnit 3.5.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.

...............................................................  63 / 134 ( 47%)
.........................E.....

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 11.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) SomeClassTest::testSomething
Undefined property: SomeClass::$var

/path/to/SomeClass.php:99
/path/to/SomeClassTest.php:15

FAILURES!
Tests: 94, Assertions: 170, Errors: 1.

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I'm happy for the reported file and line to be either the first or last entry in the stack trace. The deepest call is the actual source of the issue. Jumping to the top-level call means I can use  to step down into the call stack. I would prefer the latter, `SomeClassTest.php:15` in the example above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is the phrasing of the `%Z` rule. First I came up with this:

```
:set errorformat=%E%n)\ %.%#,%Z%f:%l,%C%m,%-G%.%#
```

That'll catch the *first* filename and associate that with the error message.

For some reason, association the *last* filename mentioned was a whole lot harder. I wasn't able to do it with `efm`, but instead hacked together this Python filter:

```
import sys                                                                  
import re
errors = []
OTHER = 0
MESSAGE = 1
FILE_LINE = 2
next_is = OTHER
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if (next_is == OTHER):
        if (re.search("^[0-9]+\)", line)):
            next_is = MESSAGE
    elif (next_is == MESSAGE):
        errors.append([line, ''])
        next_is = FILE_LINE
    elif (next_is == FILE_LINE):
        if (re.search("^.+:[0-9]+", line)):
            errors[-1][1] = line
        elif (len(line) == 0 and len(errors[-1][1]) > 0):
            next_is = OTHER

for error in errors:
    print "{0}:{1}".format(error[1], error[0])
```

This will capture all the errors and output them in a single-line format. The associated filename and line number are the *last* ones mentioned for the error. This script clobbers all other output, but that'd be solved by adding e.g. a `print line` after `line = line.strip()`.

Comment: I've posted the code in a plugin on Github:

https://github.com/afternoon/vim-phpunit

Comment: Looking at it again, maybe the reason it didn't work was that `%+C%$` would always match before `%Z%$` and therefore the multi-line message never got "closed" properly.

Comment: Hmm, seems this matches the last function call (first in the list, `SomeClass.php:99`). This makes it hard to diagnose a problem when common test functions are called by multiple tests. Using the first function call (last in the list - `SomeClassTest.php:15`) would be more useful as `C-]` allows you to step into calls without stack information only available at runtime.

Comment: I think you need to use the filename stack then, `%P` and `%G`... I'll see if I can tweak it :)

Comment: meant `%Q` instead of `%G`, duh.

Comment: Seems those are intended for capturing a filename that then applies to multiple errors, rather than capturing one of many filenames for a single error. However, if they can be abused for this purpose, great :-).

Comment: You're right. I gave up and wrote a Python filter, see the updated answer. `help efm` has examples on how to use such filters.